# Why render props is not working with Curly Braces in render function?

Tags: reactjs

I am working in React Render Props. So, whenever I use Curly Braces in *render* function and passing as a props of *Counter* component my *clickCounter* component is not called. But it is working when I use *parenthesis* instead of curly braces. So why is this happening? Why curly braces is not working in a arrow function but parenthesis is working.

**clickCounter.js**

```
import React from "react";

const ClickCounter = (props) => {
  console.log("called");
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {props.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={props.handleIncrement}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ClickCounter;
```

***Counter.js***

```
import React from "react";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return { count: prevState.count + 1 };
    });
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    const { render } = this.props;
    return render(this.state.count, this.handleIncrement);
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

***App.js not working***

```
import React from "react";
import ClickCounter from "./HOC/ClickCounter";
// import HoverCounter from "./HOC/hoverCounter";
import Counter from "./RenderProps/Counter";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <ClickCounter></ClickCounter>
      <HoverCounter></HoverCounter> */}
      <Counter
        render={(a, b) => {
          <ClickCounter count={a} handleIncrement={b}></ClickCounter>;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***App.js Working***

```
import React from "react";
import ClickCounter from "./HOC/ClickCounter";
// import HoverCounter from "./HOC/hoverCounter";
import Counter from "./RenderProps/Counter";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <ClickCounter></ClickCounter>
      <HoverCounter></HoverCounter> */}
      <Counter
        render={(a, b) => (
          <ClickCounter count={a} handleIncrement={b}></ClickCounter>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Why there is difference between () and {} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are different:

```js
const myFunc1 () => (true)
const myFunc2 () => {true}
```

The first case is a function that returns the boolean true.

The second case is a function whose body is just the expression `true`, but it returns nothing.

The correct version of `myFunc2` that works like `myFunc1` is this:

```js
const myFunc2 () => { return true }
```

This is the problem in your broken App code: when you use curly braces, you're defining a block scope for the function's body, and a function like that must use the `return` keyword to actually return something.

This difference is especially relevant when you want an arrow function to return an object, like so:

```js
// this breaks!
const getMyPet = () => { species: 'dog', name: 'Fido' }
```

It's true that this is a valid object initializer: `{ species: 'dog', name: 'Fido' }`, but in this context it creates ambiguity for the JS parser, because `{` and `}` are how you delimit a function body. For this reason, if you want an arrow to return a plain object, you must wrap that object with parentheses:

```js
// this works
const getMyPet = () => ({ species: 'dog', name: 'Fido' })
```